# tslint extension identifying non-deprecated version of subscribe as deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

Wondering if anyone else is seeing this issue (Yes I know I should switch to eslint but haven't gotten there yet).  My tslint extension in vscode is highlighting all of my subscriptions as deprecated, however, they're not.  If I f12 into them they take me to the non-deprecated version:

```
subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

Here's one, just incase I'm loosing my mind:

```
poll.subscribe(LastValue => {
    this.runsomecode();
});
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension and restarting vscode and my computer (the usual IT issues).  Please help, this highlighting is driving me insane.  I can also run "npm run lint" and the subscriptions are not found as lint errors.

Comment: Just started seeing this today, too. Haven't taken the time to look into it yet, but I would be curious if someone finds something.

Comment: Glad it's not just me (but also sorry, it sucks)! Yeah started out of the blue for me yesterday around 4PM ish. Don't think any updates were installed so not sure what's going on.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43053) it is a vsCode version bug, so just waiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a typescript bug in v4.2.2 and will be addressed in next release per https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43053

posted from an answer in the comments as the OP did not post after several days